# Deleting row in a list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material, mean-stack

I have an array of JSON objects that contain 2 key and values. This array is populated in a md-list to show its content. However when I try to delete a row in the list, it doesn't delete the row in the list UI.

Following is a simplified example:

```
           <md-list>
                <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Learning Center Activity Name</md-subheader>
                <md-list-item class="md-2-line"
                              ng-repeat="learningCenterActivityName in $parent.mondayLearningCenterActivityNameList track by $index"
                              ng-hide="$parent.mondayLearningCenterActivityNameList[$index]==undefined">
                    <div class="md-list-item-text compact">
                        <h3>{{learningCenterActivityName}}</h3>
                        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" flex="none"
                                   ng-click="deleteLearningCenterListItem($index)">x
                        </md-button>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>-->
```

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
$scope.deleteLearningCenterListItem = function(index) {
         delete $scope.mondayLearningCenterActivityNameList[index];
};
```

Comment: This seems to provide right information on how to add or delete any item in javascript array. - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/little-bit-angularjs-push-splice-paul-anthony-deehan

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.splice` instead of `delete` and AngularJS will update:

```
$scope.deleteLearningCenterListItem = function(index) {
    $scope.mondayLearningCenterActivityNameList.splice(index, 1);
};
```